# How to check a 2D array is a sub array of a bigger array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, valueerror, sub-array

I am getting this error while initializing this new array based on the matches of subarrays. I want to check the points/indices where subarray B exists within A. My requirement is that the subarray is 2D or 1D and the bigger array is 3D or 2D respectively. I want to know if there is a function that python provides for it? or I will have to check it index by index?
Error:
*ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()*

```
A = np.array([[ 2, 3, 0, 5, 1, 1, 2 ],
                  [ 0, 5, 1, 1, 6, 7, 8],
                  [2, 6, 3, 0, 5, 1, 6]
                 
                 ]);
    n = len(A);
    B = np.array([ 3, 0, 5, 1 ]);
    m = len(B);
    e = np.array([255 if (i == B.any()) else 0 for i in A])
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `(i == B).any()`?  Are you asking if any element of `B` is equal to `i`?

Comment: Not any. If all of elements of B exist in same sequence in A then give true